# How to increase offset parameter while parsing Json data using Retrofit in Android?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

> [click Here to see Images of Json data Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLljB.png)

Here i pass offset=0 i get 100 record when i increase offset like offset=1 i get next 100 record here around offset value is more than 5000. How i parse this data in single call And set to Spinner.

I parse this Json data using Ratrofit in Spinner.Here is My Code.

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.getSateName(getResources().getString(R.string.appkey));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            JSONObject resp = null;
            try {
                String s = response.body().string();
                resp = new JSONObject(s);
                JSONArray record = resp.getJSONArray("records");
                List<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < record.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject child0 = (JSONObject) record.get(i);
                    String stateName = child0.getString("state");
                    str.add(stateName);
                }
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.spinner_apperance, str);
                spstate.setAdapter(adapter);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

Here i get only 100 record of state how i get total state record in spinner??

Comment: dont have to parse data in retrofit..retrofit does that automatically

Comment: yaa.. but see picture and tell me how i pass offset parameter because it gives only 100 records when i increase offset like offset=1 it give next 100 then i pass offset=2 it gives next 100 records . how i parse all records in single call???